# How do I return variables from a function in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to make a simple dice rolling GUI where you press a button and a dice rolls and gives you the output in a label. When I run my code I get the error that "diceOutput" is not defined. Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()

window.title("Dice")

def rollDice():
    diceOutput = str(random.randint(1,6))
    return diceOutput

roll = Button(window, text="Roll", command=rollDice)
output = Label(window, textvariable=diceOutput)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `textvariable=` needs special class `tkinter.StringVar()` - which has methods `get()` and `set()`. When you change text in `StringVar` then it automatically change text with all widgets which used `textvariable=` to assign this variable.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the label and button in the window, using a layout manager. Here I used `.pack()`

You do not need the global variable `diceOutput`.

Then you need to assign the new dice roll to the text label, once the button has been clicked:

```
from tkinter import *
import random

window = Tk()
window.title("Dice")

def rollDice():
    dice_roll_result = str(random.randint(1,6))
    outlbl['text'] = dice_roll_result

roll = Button(window, text="Roll", command=rollDice)
roll.pack()
outlbl = Label(window, text='')
outlbl.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Reblochon Masque showed you don't need `textvariable=` to change text in `Label`

... but if you use `textvariable=` then you have to use class `StringVar()` / `IntVar()` / etc.
and you have to use `variable.set()` to change value in `StringVar()` / `IntVar()` / etc.
 and it will change text in `Label`

(BTW: to get value you have to use `variable.get()`)

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def roll_dice():
    dice_output.set( random.randint(1, 6) )

# --- main ---

window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Dice")

roll = tk.Button(window, text="Roll", command=roll_dice)
roll.pack()

dice_output = tk.StringVar()

output = tk.Label(window, textvariable=dice_output)
output.pack()

window.mainloop()
```